# Overriding languages in library project

Tags: android, localization

I have a library project that defines the basic structure of an app.  I then have several apps based on this library project.  To put things in perspective, the library project has about 300 classes (activities, services, data model representation, etc.)  Individual apps have about 2-3 classes each, essentially the main activity plus a bit of code customising whatever the library project creates.

The library project contains string resources in several languages (English, Russian, and French at present, but will be extended as translations are ready).  The actual apps based on this library project may not require all of these translations.  So, is there any way to disable specific languages in the library project from the main app project?

To give a simple example, the library project has English as the main language and also contains resources for Russian and French.  The application must always be presented in English (client's requirement).  Naturally, I define the application specific resources in English only, but whenever strings from the library project are used, they do come in Russian or French when the device locale is set to one of them.  I need to somehow, from the main app, indicate that I only want to use English resources, regardless of the device locale.  Is there a way to do this?  If yes, how?

Comment: The first thing that comes to the mind is Android Studio/Gradle. Any chances that you might be able to build the library separately for each project?

Comment: imo it is not possibile if you let android manages strings localisation, but I do think the programmatically is achievable. Through reflection you can read R.strings and retrieve all the english string's id and then you can create your own dictionary id -> strings. For instance you can embedded the others string file in the assets or download from the web

Comment: @shoerat The whole point of the library project is that it's written once - and then I simply include it into my main project.  If I have to modify the library for each of the apps, that defeats the purpose of the library.

Comment: @AleksG, I did not mean to modify the library, rather just build different variations (i.e., with different variations of locale stings included)

Comment: @shoerat but that still means maintaining multiple versions of the lib...